# Setting response headers in WebSocket server and verify in client using npm WebSocket server

Tags: node.js, npm, websocket, network-protocols

I am creating a mock web server using ws library of node.js:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#api-docs

I need to set a protocol in `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header and send it to client, then verify the header on client side.

I tried below options:

```
wss.on('headers', function (headers) {
    console.log("on headers");
    headers.push(`sec-websocket-protocol: ${protocol}`);
})
```

Also this:

```
 var msg = {
        message: message,
        "sec-websocket-protocol": protocol
    };
ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

Nothing seems to work currently. Also on client side I am not sure on how to verify this header?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to mess with the headers yourself.

On the client side you list the protocols as the second arguemtn to the `Websocket` constructor.

```
const ws = new WebSocket(ws_url, ["protocol-1", "protocol-2", "protocol-3"]);
```

On the server side, you need to pass a `handleProtocols` function, to chose one of the available protocols.

```
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    ...
    handleProtocols: (protocols, client) => {
        var protocol = /* choose one from protocols argument */;
        return protocol;
    },
    ...
});
```

Then on the client side you get the chosen protocol on the [`protocol` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/protocol) on your WebSocket object.

```
ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log("WS opened; protocol chosen:", this.protocol);
};
ws.onmessage = function(data) {
    if (this.protocol in protocol_handlers) {
        protocol_handlers[this.protocol](data.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have done that also.But how to check if header is set correctly?